# Changes made in then method are not saved

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, async-await, firebase-authentication

I have a user that is signed in at FirebaseAuthentication. Now I want to show the current user's email address in a Text. For that, I store it in a variable **email**.

This is my code right now.

```
String email = "Not Logged In";
FirebaseAuth.instance
    .currentUser()
    .then((FirebaseUser user) {
      email = user.email;
      print(email);
});
```

The right address is printed, but after the .then() method the value of email turns back to "Not Logged in".
How do I manage to save the value also after the then method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is pure asynchronous issue. Here's how it works.

```
1 => String email = "Not Logged In";
2 => FirebaseAuth.instance
3 =>    .currentUser()
4 =>    .then((FirebaseUser user) {
5 =>       email = user.email;
6 =>       print(email);
         });
7 =>     print(email);
```

The order of the execution is: 1,2,3,4, 7, 5, 6. This means the print outside the `then` block will be executed immediately after the block is added to the stack.

Now there is another way to do this, maybe more readable for you. Something like:

```
void testFunc() async {
     String email = "Not Logged In";
     FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
     email = user.email;
     print(email);
}
```

You have to pay attention to two things:

1. the `async` keyword, which tells the compiler that this whole method is async.
2. the `await` keyword which similar with the `then`.

Comment: Yes, that woks. I already tried that but wanted to use a local variable which seems to be not possible. Now I am using a global one and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Patrick what do you mean it doesn't work with local variable ?

Comment: I can Not Return a Not-Future-Type in the async function, so I can Not set the local Variable to a value inside my Build-Methode. If I have a global one instead, I can set it inside the async function, so I can Save the changed value.(Sorry for spelling, its my phone)

Answer (score 0):

`currentUser()` returns `Future`,

So you just need to wait the task to finish

```
String email = "Not Logged In";
await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .currentUser()
    .then((FirebaseUser user) {
      email = user.email;
      print(email);
});
print(email);
```